# Month and Year is not changing correctly in flutter date scroller

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using a date scroller with the month and year written on top. The month and date are not correct. The next month shows after almost 1.5 months. How can I make it change correctly when the next month's first date is shown on the screen? I ask chatgpt to calculate this for me. And it is calculated on the basis of container width and I want that it change the month and year on the basis of the date shown on the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class DatePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const DatePicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DatePicker> createState() => _DatePickerState();
}

class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime startingDate;
  late DateTime endingDate;
  final String fontFamily = "Urbanist"; // Define the font family here
  final DateFormat monthYearFormat = DateFormat.yMMMM('en_US');

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  String currentMonthYear = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startingDate = DateTime(2023, 1, 1);
    endingDate = DateTime.now(); // Update the ending date to today's date
    currentMonthYear = monthYearFormat.format(startingDate);
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(_onScroll);
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    final scrollOffset = _scrollController.offset;
    final dayWidth = 58.0; // Adjust this value as per your design

    final visibleDays = (scrollOffset / dayWidth).round();
    final currentDate = startingDate.add(Duration(days: visibleDays));
    final updatedMonthYear = monthYearFormat.format(currentDate);

    setState(() {
      currentMonthYear = updatedMonthYear;
    });
  }

  void scrollDays(int days) {
    final currentIndex = _scrollController.offset ~/ 58.0;
    final scrollIndex = currentIndex + days;

    _scrollController.animateTo(
      scrollIndex * 58.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final totalDays = endingDate.difference(startingDate).inDays + 1;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                scrollDays(-7); // Scroll 7 days back
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_left_outlined, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            Text(
              currentMonthYear, // Display dynamically updated month name and year
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: fontFamily,
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                scrollDays(7); // Scroll 7 days forward
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right_outlined, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 18),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: _scrollController,
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Row(
            children: List.generate(
              totalDays, // Show dates from startingDate to endingDate
                  (index) {
                final currentDate = startingDate.add(Duration(days: index));
                final dayName = DateFormat('E').format(currentDate);
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    }),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.095,
                      height: 70,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: selectedIndex == index ? Color(0xff6842FF) : Color(0xff35383F),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            dayName.substring(0, 1),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontFamily: fontFamily, // Use the font family here
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 6),
                          Text(
                            "${currentDate.day}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: fontFamily, // Use the font family here
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```